# How to interpret with numeric cell with general formatting with apache POI event library

Tags: xml, excel, format, cell

I am Apache POI event library to read excel files, when cell is of type numeric and does not have any formatting associated with it I get the absolute value which excel saves. I would like to know how excel displays it as 40.33 as I need to do the same. I know about formatlistener and it does not work in this situation.

I would like to know how excel interprets a cell with general format. For example, if I have 40.33 in a cell it is saved as 40.332999999999998. With general formatting how does excel know to display 40.33 when the value is saved with 16 decimal places.

```
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"xmlns:x14ac="http:
//schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" mc:Ignorable="x14ac">

<dimension ref="A1:A3"/>

<sheetViews>

<sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">

<selection activeCell="A5" sqref="A5"/>

</sheetView>
</sheetViews>
<sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/>
<sheetData>
<row r="1" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
<c r="A1">
<v>40.332999999999998</v>
</c>
</row>
<row r="2" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
<c r="A2" s="1">
<v>20</v>
</c>
</row>
<row r="3" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
<c r="A3" s="2">
<v>0.2</v>
</c>
</row>
</sheetData>
<pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
<pageSetup orientation="portrait" r:id="rId1"/>
</worksheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution is to use NumberToTextConverter class in poi to get the data to look like how excel shows it.